# UWP - Acrylic brush always falls back to solid color

Tags: c#, windows, xaml, uwp

I've been trying to implement new acrylic design language but applied acrylic brush always falls back to its fallback color. I use Fall Creators Update and my application minimal target is Fall Creators Update as well. When I use some modern application like calculator for example, acrylic seems working..
Thanks for any suggestions.

Example

```
<Rectangle  
x:Name="GameTree" 
Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="5" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" 
Fill="{ThemeResource MyAcrylicBrush}"/>
```

Brush definition

```
<AcrylicBrush x:Key="MyAcrylicBrush"
AlwaysUseFallback="False"
BackgroundSource="HostBackdrop"
TintColor="#FF00ff00"
TintOpacity="0.8"
FallbackColor="#FF000066"
/>
```

Comment: So there's some caveats to that brush that would encourage a couple questions. Is it running on a machine with the win10 Fall Creators update? Is the machine in battery saving mode at all? Is it in high-contrast mode? Is the Transparency turned off in the Personalization Settings? Is the hardware running it lower-end? Is the machine an xbox, hololens, or running in tablet mode? Any one of those considerations will force the condition for fallback.

Comment: Well, as I wrote in other applications it works pretty well. I use fall c. update, no saving mode, no high contracts, transparency turned on, hardware is pretty decent, no tablet mode etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in specifiyng CacheMode="BitmapCache" attribute on the page xaml element. After removing it acrylic brushes work just fine.

Comment: For reference, setting BitmapCache on your Page root is more than likely going to *very* negatively effect your performance, especially if you have anything moving on page.

Comment: Must confirm. UI is much snapier now.

Answer (score 0):

[`Acrylic`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.media.acrylicbrush) material has provided more different Tint opacity theme to use. If you want realize the feature like Window calculator, you could use `SystemControlChromeHighAcrylicWindowMediumBrush` ThemeResource directly.

```
<Rectangle  
    x:Name="GameTree" 
    HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" 
    Fill="{ThemeResource SystemControlChromeHighAcrylicWindowMediumBrush}">
</Rectangle>
```

> but applied acrylic brush always falls back to its fallback color.

If the [`BackgroundSource`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.media.acrylicbackgroundsource) property  is `HostBackdrop`. when the UWP window is not active, The brush samples from the content behind the app window and the `FallbackColor` will be recovered. For your requirement, you could set `BackgroundSource` as `Backdrop`. Or you could set `FallbackColor` Non-prominent color such as white.

```
<AcrylicBrush x:Key="MyAcrylicBrush"      
    BackgroundSource="HostBackdrop"
    TintColor="#FF00ff00"
    TintOpacity="0.1"        
    FallbackColor="#F8F8FF"
  />
```

[image]

For more you could refer [Acrylic material](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/style/acrylic) official document.